# Why use MongoDB and Elasticsearch together?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch is a search engine, and MongoDB is a NOSQL-based data store.
I saw a lot of cases using MongoDB and Elasticsearch together.
Usually stored in MongoDB and synchronized it to elasticsearch and analyzed it.
But I do not understand.
Data stored in MongoDB stores Data on elasticsearch anyway.
Why save duplicate Data?
Why need MongoDB?

Comment: This will get closed as it's mostly opinion based, but there are many possible use cases to require this, let's take a basic use case of user posts ( that contain text ). You will probably want the NOSQL benefits to store and aggregate many parameters around that, and also allow text search capabilities ( in scale ).

Comment: @TomSlabbaert, but elasticsearch on its own is also a NOSQL db

Comment: @TomSlabbaert In that case, can not it be resolved using elasticsearch or MongoDB? I wonder why I use it together.
Because it is duplicated.

Comment: as you said elastic is a search engine, and apart from it's prebuilt aggregations it's really hard to paginate over a large set of results, technically you could do everything with any db in the world (and involving some code) but you'd want to utilize a DB's strength when you do it.
mongo's text index is limited and can not really offer the same text search capabilities as elastic, and elastic can't really offer the aggregation power of mongo.

Comment: @TomSlabbaert so, do you use the same value in a way that stores the same value in MongoDB and Elasticsearch?

Comment: Look at elastic as extended full text search functionality to mongoDB document database storage ...